# How to set Default action in Android from coding?

Tags: android

Once my Home Screen app 'ABC' is installed on the device & when the user presses the Home Button, he is prompted with the Default Action Android dialog to choose between the Default Home & my ABC app.

My use case is to keep on prompting the user - a bit infrequently though, with this Default Action dialog till he selects my App as default.

How we can default action in android ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before ICS (and maybe Honeycomb), you could set the preferred activity using the [PackageManager#addPreferredActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPreferredActivity%28android.content.IntentFilter,%20int,%20android.content.ComponentName%5b%5d,%20android.content.ComponentName%29) method.

But as stated in the documentation :

> This is a protected API that should not have been available to third party applications. It is the platform's responsibility for assigning preferred activities and this can not be directly modified.

This indeed could be used by Malware to change what applications the launcher icons start. I would really advise you not to use it and instead let your users the choice to make themselves your launcher their default launcher.

Answer (score 0):

call the below intent when you need to see the 'launcher' selection dialog, unless one of the launcher apps is set as default

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
homeIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Comment: Above in the pick you can see two action i want to default snowmanApp default from coding section, can i do it?